# How to enable and disable action on switch preference in android

Tags: switchpreference

This is not working with switch preference please help .......to write another code..

```
SwitchPreference uiTestModePref = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("switch");
uiTestModePref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {    
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
        boolean check = (preference).isEnabled();
        if (check) {
            android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No", toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `isChecked()` instead of `isEnabled()`